# pyvmomi 5.5 and vsphere 6 - Can I get tags?

Tags: tags, vsphere, pyvmomi

I've wanted to get the vmware-tags from vSphere 5.5 using pyvmomi 5.5 - which is not possible because of limitations in the vSphere 5.5 Python API.

But now when we've upgraded vSphere to 6.0 - is it possible to get the tags somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This will provide the python bindings using pyvmomi for the tagging api
http://developercenter.vmware.com/web/sdk/60/vcloudsuite-python

Answer (score 0):

For those who still looking for recipe in 2021 with vsphere 6.5+, you may obtain tags using [REST API](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/vsphere-automation/v7.0U1/cis/rest/com/vmware/cis/tagging/tag/get/) or [vSphere Automation SDK](https://github.com/vmware/vsphere-automation-sdk-python).
You can find full examples [here](https://gist.github.com/em2er/74cdabdd0fd337f382939df3e5f6a68e) (for the REST API) and in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594178/7705264) (for the SDK)