# Get VM tags using pyvmomi in vSphere 6.5

Tags: python-3.x, automation, vsphere, pyvmomi

I am trying to filter VMs with a Python3 script by using pyvmomi.

Environment:

```
Versions:
vSphere: 6.5
Python: 3.7.7
pyvmomi: 6.5
```

At this very moment this is the code I bet for:

```
    si = SmartConnectNoSSL(
        host=config['host'],
        user=config['username'],
        pwd=password,
        port=int(config['port']),
    )
    # disconnect vc
    atexit.register(Disconnect, si)

    content = si.RetrieveContent()
    obj_view = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(
        content.rootFolder, [vim.VirtualMachine], True)
    vms_list = obj_view.view
    obj_view.Destroy()
    for vm in vms_list:
        print(vm.name)
        print(vm.tag)
```

Presumably, `vm.tag` should return an array of all vim.Tag objects. Nonetheless, all the arrays are empty but the following one:

```
vCenter 6.5                                                                                                         
(vim.Tag) [                                                                                                         
   (vim.Tag) {                                                                                                      
      dynamicType = <unset>,                                                                                        
      dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],                                                                 
      key = 'SYSTEM/COM.VMWARE.VIM.VC'                                                                              
   }                                                                                                                
]
```

After going through all VMs in the cluster, this is the only machine that is apparently having a tag. Btw, I already created a few tags and assigned them to some VMs as a test. But still, pyvmomi is not retrieving the tags from the VMs.

How can this be possible? Am I missing any detail?

Comment: Unfortunately, the pyvmomi can't get the tags. If you want to get the tags, need using which the vSphere Automation SDK for Python or REST API of VCSA. see: https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/issues/765

Answer (score 2):

It is sad, [but](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2130130)

> A tag association is not stored with its object and is not a part of the object's lifecycle.

However, as @sky_jokerxx said, you may use [vSphere Automation SDK](https://github.com/vmware/vsphere-automation-sdk-python) for Python. The following code demonstrates obtaining tag names and their categories for all virtual machines in vCenter:

```py
from vmware.vapi.vsphere.client import create_vsphere_client

client = create_vsphere_client(
    server='my-company-vcenter.com',
    username='my_login',
    password='my_password',
    session=None)

cat_dict = {}
for id in client.tagging.Category.list():
    cat = client.tagging.Category.get(id)
    cat_dict[cat.id] = cat.name

tag_dict = {}
for id in client.tagging.Tag.list():
    tag = client.tagging.Tag.get(id)
    tag_dict[id] = tag

vms = client.vcenter.VM.list()
vm_objs = [{'id': v.vm, 'type': 'VirtualMachine'} for v in vms]

vm_tags = {}
for vm in client.tagging.TagAssociation.list_attached_tags_on_objects(vm_objs):
    cat_tag_dict = {}
    for ti in vm.tag_ids:
        cat_name = cat_dict[tag_dict[ti].category_id]
        if cat_name not in cat_tag_dict:
            cat_tag_dict[cat_name] = []
        cat_tag_dict[cat_name].append(tag_dict[ti].name)
    vm_tags[vm.object_id.id] = cat_tag_dict
```

`vm_tags` contains `Dict{vm.id: Dict{category_name: List[tag_name]}}` as a result, for example we have 2 VMs  with following category=tags accordingly:

- vm-30116: TEAM=backend, BACKUP=daily, BACKUP=weekly
- vm-31423: TEAM=frontend

Your `vm_tags` will look like:

```json
"vm-30116": 
{
  "TEAM": ["backend"],
  "BACKUP": ["daily", "weekly"]
}, 
"vm-31423": 
{
  "TEAM": ["frontend"],
}
```

Also, you can use pure [REST API](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/vsphere-automation/v7.0U1/cis/rest/com/vmware/cis/tagging/tag/get/). Full example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/em2er/74cdabdd0fd337f382939df3e5f6a68e).